# Builtin equivalent of numpy ndim

Tags: python

Is there a buil-in equivalent of numpy's ndim?
I would like to be able to consiely discriminate between "aaa" and ["aaa"] (string and iterable sequence of strings).

Comment: `ndim` wouldn't distinguish between `['aaa']` and `['aaa', 'bbb']` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific use case, assuming that you can only have a string, list of a single string or list of strings. You can do a simple isinstance check.

```
x = data # data is whatever you are receiving
if instance(x,str):
    print("x is a string")
elif isinstance(x,list):
    if len(x) == 1:
         print("x is a list of a single string")
    else:
         print("x is a list of multiple strings")
else:
    print("I should not get this datatype")
```